# Javascript code to open a subtab in console is not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have written logic to open a subtab with visualforce page. on clicking a custom button. But when clicking on the button the visualforce page is opening in classic view not in console. Could some one help me to fix the logic such that clicking the custom button should open the VF page in console view.

```
         {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")} 
         {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/33.0/integration.js")}

          var sforceObject = '';
            if (typeof window.parent.sforce != 'undefined') {
               sforceObject = window.parent.sforce;
              } else {
               sforceObject = sforce;
              }

              var openSubtab = function(result){ 

       sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id,'/apex/CasePage?
       cid={!Case.Id}', true, 'Sample', null); 
       }; 

       if (sforce.console.isInConsole()){ 
       sforceObject.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab); 
       }else{
       window.parent.location.href="/apex/CasePage?cid={!Case.Id}";
       }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: resolved. Thanks. updated the question with correct code.